# how to map receiptid to sent message in smack

Tags: java, android, smack, asmack

I am sending message using asmack from a client. I am sending message using xmppconnection.send  and added this                      DeliveryReceiptManager.addDeliveryReceiptRequest(msg);

before sending.
And on delivery of message i added a listner

```
DeliveryReceiptManager.getInstanceFor(connection).addReceiptReceivedListener(new ReceiptReceivedListener() {                    
@Override
public void onReceiptReceived(String arg0, String arg1, String arg2) {
```

in which i am getting receiptid,

I want to know how will i map this receiptid to the send message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the request and from the msg.getPacketId() i am getting the packet id, which i check on receipt.

```
                 DeliveryReceiptManager.addDeliveryReceiptRequest(msg);
                 System.out.println("packetid:"+msg.getPacketID());

                connection.sendPacket(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [third argument of the `onReceiptReceived` callback](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/receipts/ReceiptReceivedListener.html) is the receipt ID, which is the stanza/message ID of the packet which got received, ie. this receipt is for.

You can get the message ID with `Packet.getPacketID()`